# Using MediaRecorder i stored video from web camera and than send data by an AJAX call to my django backend. But data is corrupted

Tags: html, django, ajax, mediarecorder

Using MediaRecorder i stored video from web camera and than send data by an AJAX call to my django backend. Their im storing video in (mp4 or webM) format. The issue is that stored video is corrupted because other than VLC player no other one is running file. The main issue is that than im sending this video to a python code which than extract audio from video. to do this pyhton script first take video duration to process it. As file is corrupted, in VLC file is running but duration bar is not showing anything. So, what i think is that data is not storing the way i want.

Im new to django and specially to frontend so please help me with this. Suggest me any alternative i just want my video to be stored correctly also with video there is an audio parameter as well. Im separately sending audio so i somehow bypass the python script which extract audio from video file. But audio sent using AJAX is empty or i think corrupted.

Here is JS code at frontend side.

```js
const preview = document.getElementById("preview");
        const startButton = document.getElementById("startButton");
        const stopButton = document.getElementById("stopButton");
        const recorded = document.getElementById("recorded");
        const saveButton = document.getElementById("saveButton");
        const csrfToken = document.querySelector('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').value;
        let mediaRecorder;
        let recordedVideoChunks = [];
        let recordedAudioChunks = [];

        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            audio: true,
            video: true
          }).then(stream => {
            preview.srcObject = stream;
            preview.play();
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
              mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp9,opus'
            });
            mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
              if (e.data && e.data.size > 0) {
                if (e.data.type.indexOf('video') !== -1) {
                  recordedVideoChunks.push(e.data);
                } else if (e.data.type.indexOf('audio') !== -1) {
                  recordedAudioChunks.push(e.data);
                }
              }
            };
            mediaRecorder.onstop = function() {
              const videoBlob = new Blob(recordedVideoChunks, {type: 'video/webm'});
              const audioBlob = new Blob(recordedAudioChunks, {type: 'audio/webm'});
              recorded.src = URL.createObjectURL(videoBlob);
              recorded.controls = true;
              saveButton.disabled = false;
              stream.getTracks().forEach(function(track) {
                track.stop();
              });

            };
          });

        startButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
          recordedVideoChunks = [];
          recordedAudioChunks = [];
          mediaRecorder.start();
          startButton.disabled = true;
          stopButton.disabled = false;
          saveButton.disabled = true;
        });

        stopButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
          mediaRecorder.stop();
          startButton.disabled = false;
          stopButton.disabled = true;
          preview.srcObject.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop()); // stop camera and mic
          preview.hidden = true; // hide preview video element
        });

        saveButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
          const formData = new FormData();
          formData.append("csrfmiddlewaretoken", csrfToken);
          formData.append("video", new Blob(recordedVideoChunks, {type: 'video/webm'}));
          formData.append("audio", new Blob(recordedAudioChunks, {type: 'audio/webm'}));
          $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:7000/vedio/",
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function() {
              alert("Video saved successfully.");
            },
            error: function() {
              alert("Error saving video.");
            }
          });
        });
```

Django Backend side code for storing video

```js
if request.method == 'POST':
        video_file = request.FILES.get('video')
        audio_file = request.FILES.get('audio')
        if not video_file or not audio_file:
            return HttpResponseBadRequest('Video or audio file is missing.')
        try:
            with open('output.webm', 'wb') as output:
                for chunk in video_file.chunks():
                    output.write(chunk)
                for chunk in audio_file.chunks():
                    output.write(chunk)
            return HttpResponse('Video saved successfully.')
        except Exception as e:
            return HttpResponseServerError('Error saving video: ' + str(e))
```